# Post JSON Data with Key and Values ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am posting a JSON data with url and it's parameters. The problem is, when i post it in Postman i gets "status": "Success","msg": "You Membership Form Submitted SuccessFully" but when I post it in my Xcode 7.2.1 then it gives `"status":"Failed","msg":"You Membership Form did not Submit SuccessFully"`.So please suggest me how to solve it. The way i am doing is as follows :-

```
NSError *error;
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session=[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url111=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dnddemo.com/lifestyle/development/membership_life_api.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url111 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *mapData=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"_levelOfMembershipTableView",@"menu-291",@"_upgradeMembershipTableView",@"menu-565",@"_detailsTableView",@"menu-696",@"_txtFirstNameMembership.text",@"text-708",@"_txtLastNameMembership.text",@"text-274",@"_txtDOBMembership.text",@"text-443",@"_txtCompanyNameMembership.text",@"text-970",@"_txtJobTitleMembership.text",@"text-961",@"_txtAddressMembership.text",@"text-785",@"_txtCityMembership.text",@"text-482",@"_txtPostCodeMembership.text",@"text-760",@"_countryTableView",@"menu-19",@"_txtEmailMembership.text",@"text-577",@"_txtHomePhoneMembership.text",@"text-760",@"_txtMobilePhoneMembership.text",@"text-394",@"_txtWorkPhoneMembership.text",@"text-914",@"_contactByTableView",@"menu-373",@"_interestedInTableView",@"menu-527",@"_hearAboutUsTableView",@"menu-997", nil];
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:mapData,nil];
NSString *createJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *finalParams = @{@"field_name_value": createJSON};
[request setHTTPBody:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:finalParams]];
NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask=[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) 
{
    NSString *string=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Result is=%@",string);
}];
[postDataTask resume];
```

I am sending "field_name_value" as key. The parameters I am sending on postman are :-

Key - field_name_value
Value -

```
 [{ "field_value":"_levelOfMembershipTableView","field_name":"menu-291" }, { "field_value":"_upgradeMembershipTableView","field_name":"menu-565" } ,{ "field_value":"_detailsTableView","field_name":"menu-696" },{ "field_value":"_txtFirstNameMembership.text","field_name":"text-708" },{ "field_value":"_txtLastNameMembership.text","field_name":"text-274" },{ "field_value":"_txtDOBMembership.text","field_name":"text-443" },{ "field_value":"_txtCompanyNameMembership.text","field_name":"text-970" },{ "field_value":"_txtJobTitleMembership.text","field_name":"text-961" },{ "field_value":"_txtAddressMembership.text","field_name":"text-785" },{ "field_value":"_txtCityMembership.text","field_name":"text-482" },{ "field_value":"_txtPostCodeMembership.text","field_name":"text-760" },{ "field_value":"_countryTableView","field_name":"menu-19" },{ "field_value":"_txtEmailMembership.text","field_name":"text-577" },{"field_value":"_txtHomePhoneMembership.text","field_name":"text-760"},{"field_value":"_txtMobilePhoneMembership.text","field_name":"text-394"},{"field_value":"_txtWorkPhoneMembership.text","field_name":"text-914"},{"field_value":"_contactByTableView","field_name":"menu-373"},{ "field_value":"_interestedInTableView","field_name":"menu-527"},{ "field_value":"_hearAboutUsTableView","field_name":"menu-997"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is creating a dictionary, converting that to JSON data, then converting the JSON data to a string, putting the string from the JSON data into another dictionary, and then adding the output of `NSKeyedArchiver` as your HTTP body.

Three quarters of those steps are unnecessary and wrong. Simply convert your dictionary to JSON NSData (using `NSJSONSerialization`) and attach that to your request as the HTTP body.